# How can I get the parents of a merge commit in Git?

Tags: git, merge

Some Git commands take the parent as a revision; others (such as `git revert`), as a parent number. How can I get the parents for both cases?

I don’t want to use the graphical log command as that often requires scrolling down a long tree to find the second parent.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Simple `git log <hash>` called for a merge commit shows abbreviated hashes of its parents:

```
 $ git log -1 395f65d
 commit 395f65d438b13fb1fded88a330dc06c3b0951046
 Merge: 9901923 d28790d
 ...
```

`git` outputs parents according to their number: the first (leftmost) hash is for the first parent, and so on.

If all you want is just the hashes, the two equivalent choices are:

```
$ git log --pretty=%P -n 1 <commit>
$ git show -s --pretty=%P <commit>
```

`git rev-list` can also show the parents' hashes, though it will first list the hash for a commit:

```
$ git rev-list --parents -n 1 <commit>
```

If you want to examine the parents, you can refer to them directly with carats as `<commit>^1` and `<commit>^2`, e.g.:

```
git show <commit>^1
```

This does generalize; for an octopus merge you can refer to the n<sup>th</sup> parent as `<commit>^n`. You can refer to all parents with `<commit>^@`, though this doesn't work when a single commit is required. Additional suffixes can appear after the n<sup>th</sup> parent syntax (e.g. `<commit>^2^`, `<commit>^2^@`), whereas they cannot after `^@` (`<commit>^@^` isn't valid). For more on this syntax, read the [`rev-parse`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-rev-parse.html) man page.

Comment: Answering my own question: the results of 'git rev-list --parents -n 1 <somehash>' are: <somehash> <parent1> <parent2>. Ie, the parents are one numbered.

Comment: You can also use git-parents https://github.com/danielribeiro/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/git-parents. Just put it in your PATH and call $ git parents <commit> (<commit> defaults to HEAD)

Comment: @jefromi, I really want that "Also note that the normal log output does show..." part to be on the top of your answer. :)

Comment: `git log` and `git show` output very different things when there's only one parent. Prefer `git log` if you want consistency.

Comment: This answer doesn't work on my Ubuntu machine with `git (v2.17.1)`.
I do not see `Merge` file in `git log -1` output.

Answer (score 40):

The following is the simplest way I've found to view the parents of a merge

```
git show --pretty=raw 3706454
```

Comment: `git cat-file -p 3706454`  is the same but even shorter :)

Comment: Another option `git log --pretty=raw  -1 3706454`