# git CLI syntax to find right side parent of a commit

Tags: git

It appears that the `^` and `~` syntax in git only ever goes to the left parent commit (the commit into which the right parent is merged). In my specific case, I have a tree like this:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"%h" --graph
*   f5712e3
|\  
| * d0f8257
* | e1fe071
|/  
* e0fff07
```

I'm finding both `git log HEAD^ -1` and `git log HEAD~1 -1` give me the left parent `e1fe071`. What is the conventional syntax to get the right parent?

Answer (score 9):

```
$ git log HEAD^2
```

The caret allows you to choose among a commit’s immediate parents, as described in the [`git rev-parse` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html).

> `<rev>^`, *e.g.*, `HEAD^`, `v1.5.1^0`
>
> A suffix `^` to a revision parameter means the first parent of that commit object. `^<n>` means the *n*-th parent (*i.e.*, `<rev>^` is equivalent to `<rev>^1`). As a special rule, `<rev>^0` means the commit itself and is used when `<rev>` is the object name of a tag object that refers to a commit object.

To determine which is which, the output<sup>*</sup> of `git show` lists the parents in order. For example, head of the master branch in [libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2) is a merge commit, [a3ef70b](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/commit/a3ef70bb405a05c16fb533d828da2510ff751224).

```
$ git show master
commit a3ef70bb405a05c16fb533d828da2510ff751224
Merge: c4c47fc 8aba3d4
Author: Edward Thomson <ethomson@edwardthomson.com>
Date:   Tue Dec 30 11:53:55 2014 -0600

    Merge pull request #2761 from libgit2/cmn/fetch-prune

    Remote-tracking branch prunning
```

Notice the second line of output, beginning `Merge:`, that lists the parents in order. We can verify this property using `git rev-parse` as in

```bash
$ git rev-parse master^1
c4c47fc2861935d8e373319c0734ea7b2ce34a73
```

and

```bash
$ git rev-parse master^2
8aba3d47cf96e24e02601175f900f0e851077c1a
```

Inspecting [the source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c5b9256360b06efb9453c1627b78b14598e288b8/pretty.c#L531) confirms.

```c
strbuf_addstr(sb, "Merge:");

while (parent) {
    struct commit *p = parent->item;
    const char *hex = NULL;
    if (pp->abbrev)
        hex = find_unique_abbrev(p->object.sha1, pp->abbrev);
    if (!hex)
        hex = sha1_to_hex(p->object.sha1);
    parent = parent->next;

    strbuf_addf(sb, " %s", hex);
}
```

**Related answer:** [Get parents of a merge commit in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9059633/123109)

---

* The [documentation for `git show`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html#_pretty_formats) gives a caveat regarding pedigree of commits:

> If the commit is a merge, and if the pretty-format is not *oneline*, *email* or *raw*, an additional line is inserted before the *Author:* line. This line begins with "Merge: " and the sha1s of ancestral commits are printed, separated by spaces. Note that the listed commits may not necessarily be the list of the **direct** parent commits if you have limited your view of history: for example, if you are only interested in changes related to a certain directory or file.

Comment: How do you know which is which? Depending on whatever factors, a desired parent may be either on the left or on the right.

Comment: I understand your answer, although it does not address my particular issue. However since this situation occurs only once in my repository, I think I'll just resort to manual inspection.