# Getting base branch SHA on pull request in Github Action Workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

In GitHub action on pull request, I need to run some code in the context of the "current master", and later re-run the same code in the context of the PR branch.

I can check out compare a pull request to the base it is being PR-ed against. How would I find the SHA of the base branch (e.g. current master if PR is against the master)?

```yaml
jobs:
  job_on_base:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: "${{ github.base_ref }}"
      - run: |
          # Seems like I can get it here with $(git log -1 --format="%H")
          echo "My current SHA is ... ?"

  job_on_pr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: "${{ github.ref }}"
      - run: |
          echo "My current SHA is $GITHUB_SHA"
          echo "The BASE SHA is ?"
```

Answer (score 16):

If the job runs on a `pull_request` event the base sha is available as `${{ github.event.pull_request.base.sha }}`

Comment: and if anyone is looking here for branch's sha it's: `${{github.event.pull_request.head.sha}}`
https://github.com/actions/checkout#checkout-pull-request-head-commit-instead-of-merge-commit

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me was: `github.event.workflow_run.head_sha`.

The top-voted answer suggesting `github.event.pull_request.head.sha` didn't work for me.

I found this by examining all the possible data in the `github.context` object using the method suggested here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70107953

Answer (score 3):

This turned out to be a `git` question, rather than Github actions.  The `actions/checkout@v2` creates a shallow `--depth=1` clone, so to get PR's parent one can parse `git cat-file -p` output as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48913282/177275). The first (base) parent could be accessed with

```
git cat-file -p <SHA> | awk 'NR > 1 {if(/^parent/){print $2; exit}}'
```

The better approach turned out to be using `fetch-depth: 2` parameter. It allows just one job to handle both pull request and master merge cases, and can also be used with `HEAD^1` to get to the parent.

```
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      fetch-depth: 2
```