# Complete list of github actions contexts

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-artifacts

While investigating how, within github actions, I can diff the "base" version of a specific file in a repository, with the Pull Request's ("head") version of the file ... while investigating this, I found among various sources (for example, [github.community](https://github.community/t/how-do-i-get-the-git-diff-compared-to-main/179296), and *code examples* in the [github.com/actions/checkout README file](https://github.com/actions/checkout/#readme)) ... I found that the following context variables are available:

- `github.ref`
- `github.sha`
- `github.event.pull_request.head.ref`
- `github.event.pull_request.head.sha`
- `github.event.pull_request.base.ref`
- `github.event.pull_request.base.sha`

However, other than the first two (`github.ref` and `github.sha`) I *cannot find the other four in any of the github actions documentation*.

My question is this:  ***Is there any place where the full list of available context variables is documented?***

I have, for example, [found this](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context), but it only lists context variables one level down from the github context object.  I can't find documentation for the more deeply nested variables noted above.  Likely there are other context variables that may be very useful, but I can't seem to find a *complete* list, rather only those that happen to be mentioned and scatter about in various code examples.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think you want to distinguish between context variables and payloads.

Context variables are available in most cases and exceptions are documented (as you found): https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#example-printing-context-information-to-the-log

The payload, on the other hand, depends on the event type. If you run a workflow as a result of `on: pull_request` you'll get a different payload than running it as a result of `on: push` (etc..).

I have never seen docs that list all payloads, but I believe you can take inspiration from the webhooks. For example, if you run a workflow when a pull request is created, you could look at the webhook payload for pull requests here: https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#webhook-payload-example-33

Since the two **not** are documented to be the same, you might have to resort back to just dumping an event and checking what you actually get. In the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#example-printing-context-information-to-the-log-file), GitHub has an example how to dump contexts as part of a workflow:

```yaml
jobs:
  one:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Dump GitHub context
        env:
          GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJSON(github) }}
        run: echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is helpful.  I was actually thinking to dump the context as a way of exploring it but could not figure out how.  Then, since you mentioned it, a quick search found this: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#example-printing-context-information-to-the-log-file   Thanks.  Hopefully that will give me everything I need.

Comment: If you stumbled on this answer looking for a quick way to print/log all Actions contexts for debugging purposes, there is an action that allows you to do it in one line: `- uses: crazy-max/ghaction-dump-context@v1`.

Comment: The link address for my comment above has changed.  The new link is:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#example-printing-context-information-to-the-log

Answer (score 2):

Yes apparently dumping is the way to go. I have not done it myself, but I have found the dump of the `github` context in this gist very helpful: https://gist.github.com/colbyfayock/1710edb9f47ceda0569844f791403e7e

```
{
  "token": "[token]",
  "job": "notifySlack",
  "ref": "refs/pull/4/merge",
  "sha": "[shad]",
  "repository": "colbyfayock/demo-github-actions",
  "repository_owner": "colbyfayock",
  "repositoryUrl": "git://github.com/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions.git",
  "run_id": 120667610,
  "run_number": "2",
  "actor": "colbyfayock",
  "workflow": "Slack Notifications",
  "head_ref": "colbyfayock-patch-2",
  "base_ref": "master",
  "event_name": "pull_request",
  "event": {
    "action": "opened",
    "number": 4,
    "pull_request": {
      "_links": {
        "comments": {
          "href": "..."
        },
        "commits": {
          "href": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/pulls/4/commits"
        },
        "html": {
          "href": "..."
        },
        "issue": {
          "href": "..."
        },
        "review_comment": {
          "href": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/pulls/comments{/number}"
        },
        "review_comments": {
          "href": "..."
        },
        "self": {
          "href": "..."
        },
        "statuses": {
          "href": "..."
        }
      },
      "additions": 3,
      "assignee": null,
      "assignees": [],
      "author_association": "OWNER",
      "base": {
        "label": "colbyfayock:master",
        "ref": "master",
        "repo": {
          "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/{archive_format}{/ref}",
          "archived": false,
          "assignees_url": "...",
          "blobs_url": "...",
          "branches_url": "...",
          "clone_url": "https://github.com/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions.git",
          "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/collaborators{/collaborator}",
          "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/comments{/number}",
          "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/commits{/sha}",
          "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/compare/{base}...{head}",
          "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/contents/{+path}",
          "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/contributors",
          "created_at": "2020-05-30 T04:08:32 Z",
          "default_branch": "master",
          "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/deployments",
          "description": null,
          "disabled": false,
          "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/downloads",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/events",
          "fork": false,
          "forks": 0,
          "forks_count": 0,
          "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/forks",
          "full_name": "colbyfayock/demo-github-actions",
          "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/git/commits{/sha}",
          "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/git/refs{/sha}",
          "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/git/tags{/sha}",
          "git_url": "git://github.com/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions.git",
          "has_downloads": true,
          "has_issues": true,
          "has_pages": false,
          "has_projects": true,
          "has_wiki": true,
          "homepage": null,
          "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/hooks",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions",
          "id": 268006728,
          "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/issues/comments{/number}",
          "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/issues/events{/number}",
          "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/issues{/number}",
          "11": 18,
          "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/keys{/key_id}",
          "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/labels{/name}",
          "language": "JavaScript",
          "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/languages",
          "license": {
            "key": "mit",
            "name": "MIT License",
            "node_id": "[node ID]",
            "spdx_id": "MIT",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/mit"
          },
          "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/merges",
          "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/milestones{/number}",
          "mirror_url": null,
          "name": "demo-github-actions",
          "node_id": "[node id]",
          "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
          "open_issues": 2,
          "open_issues_count": 2,
          "owner": {
            "avatar_url": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1045274?v=4",
            "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/events{/privacy}",
            "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/followers",
            "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/following{/other_user}",
            "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/gists{/gist_id}",
            "gravatar_id": "",
            "html_url": "https://github.com/colbyfayock",
            "id": 1045274,
            "login": "colbyfayock",
            "node_id": "[node id]",
            "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/orgs",
            "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/received_events",
            "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/repos",
            "site_admin": false,
            "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
            "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/subscriptions",
            "type": "User",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock"
          },
          "private": false,
          "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/pulls{/number}",
          "pushed_at": "2020-05-31 T15:18:27 Z",
          "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/releases{/id}",
          "size": 52,
          "ssh_url": "git@github.com:colbyfayock/demo-github-actions.git",
          "stargazers_count": 0,
          "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/stargazers",
          "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/statuses/{sha}",
          "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/subscribers",
          "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/subscription",
          "svn_url": "https://github.com/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions",
          "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/tags",
          "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/teams",
          "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/git/trees{/sha}",
          "updated_at": "2020-05-31 T15:18:10 Z",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions",
          "watchers": 0,
          "watchers_count": 0
        },
        "sha": "[sha]",
        "user": {
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1045274?v=4",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/events{/privacy}",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/gists{/gist_id}",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/colbyfayock",
          "id": 1045274,
          "login": "colbyfayock",
          "node_id": "[node id]",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/orgs",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/received_events",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/repos",
          "site_admin": false,
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/subscriptions",
          "type": "User",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock"
        }
      },
      "body": "",
      "changed_files": 1,
      "closed_at": null,
      "comments": 0,
      "11": 18,
      "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/issues/4/comments",
      "commits": 1,
      "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/pulls/4/commits",
      "created_at": "2020-05-31 T15:18:30 Z",
      "deletions": 1,
      "diff_url": "https://github.com/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/pull/4.diff",
      "draft": false,
      "head": {
        "label": "colbyfayock:colbyfayock-patch-2",
        "ref": "colbyfayock-patch-2",
        "repo": {
          "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/{archive_format}{/ref}",
          "archived": false,
          "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/assignees{/user}",
          "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/git/blobs{/sha}",
          "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/branches{/branch}",
          "clone_url": "https://github.com/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions.git",
          "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/collaborators{/collaborator}",
          "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/comments{/number}",
          "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/commits{/sha}",
          "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/compare/{base}...{head}",
          "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/contents/{+path}",
          "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/contributors",
          "created_at": "2020-05-30 T04:08:32 Z",
          "default_branch": "master",
          "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/deployments",
          "description": null,
          "disabled": false,
          "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/downloads",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/events",
          "fork": false,
          "forks": 0,
          "forks_count": 0,
          "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/forks",
          "full_name": "colbyfayock/demo-github-actions",
          "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/git/commits{/sha}",
          "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/git/refs{/sha}",
          "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/git/tags{/sha}",
          "git_url": "git://github.com/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions.git",
          "has_downloads": true,
          "has_issues": true,
          "has_pages": false,
          "has_projects": true,
          "has_wiki": true,
          "homepage": null,
          "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/hooks",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions",
          "id": 268006728,
          "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/issues/comments{/number}",
          "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/issues/events{/number}",
          "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/issues{/number}",
          "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/keys{/key_id}",
          "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/labels{/name}",
          "language": "JavaScript",
          "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/languages",
          "license": {
            "key": "mit",
            "name": "MIT License",
            "node_id": "[node ID]",
            "spdx_id": "MIT",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/mit"
          },
          "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/merges",
          "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/milestones{/number}",
          "mirror_url": null,
          "name": "demo-github-actions",
          "node_id": "[node id]",
          "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
          "open_issues": 2,
          "open_issues_count": 2,
          "owner": {
            "avatar_url": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1045274?v=4",
            "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/events{/privacy}",
            "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/followers",
            "11": "18",
            "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/following{/other_user}",
            "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/gists{/gist_id}",
            "gravatar_id": "",
            "html_url": "https://github.com/colbyfayock",
            "id": "1045274",
            "login": "colbyfayock",
            "node_id": "[node id]",
            "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/orgs",
            "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/received_events",
            "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/repos",
            "site_admin": false,
            "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
            "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/subscriptions",
            "type": "User",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock"
          },
          "private": false,
          "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/pulls{/number}",
          "pushed_at": "2020-05-31 T15:18:27 Z",
          "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/releases{/id}",
          "size": 52,
          "ssh_url": "git@github.com:colbyfayock/demo-github-actions.git",
          "stargazers_count": 0,
          "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/stargazers",
          "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/statuses/{sha}",
          "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/subscribers",
          "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/subscription",
          "svn_url": "https://github.com/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions",
          "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/tags",
          "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/teams",
          "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/git/trees{/sha}",
          "updated_at": "2020-05-31 T15:18:10 Z",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions",
          "watchers": 0,
          "watchers_count": 0
        },
        "sha": "[sha]",
        "user": {
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1045274?v=4",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/events{/privacy}",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/gists{/gist_id}",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/colbyfayock",
          "id": 1045274,
          "login": "colbyfayock",
          "node_id": "[node id]",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/orgs",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/received_events",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/repos",
          "site_admin": false,
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/subscriptions",
          "type": "User",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock"
        }
      },
      "html_url": "https://github.com/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/pull/4",
      "id": 425626799,
      "issue_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/issues/4",
      "labels": [],
      "locked": false,
      "maintainer_can_modify": false,
      "merge_commit_sha": null,
      "mergeable": null,
      "mergeable_state": "unknown",
      "merged": false,
      "merged_at": null,
      "merged_by": null,
      "milestone": null,
      "node_id": "[node id]",
      "number": 4,
      "patch_url": "https://github.com/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/pull/4.patch",
      "rebaseable": null,
      "requested_reviewers": [],
      "requested_teams": [],
      "review_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/pulls/comments{/number}",
      "review_comments": 0,
      "review_comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/pulls/4/comments",
      "state": "open",
      "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/statuses/[sha]",
      "title": "Update README.md",
      "updated_at": "2020-05-31 T15:18:30 Z",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/pulls/4",
      "user": {
        "11": 18,
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1045274?v=4",
        "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/events{/privacy}",
        "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/followers",
        "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/following{/other_user}",
        "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/gists{/gist_id}",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/colbyfayock",
        "id": 1045274,
        "login": "colbyfayock",
        "node_id": "[node id]",
        "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/orgs",
        "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/received_events",
        "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/repos",
        "site_admin": false,
        "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
        "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/subscriptions",
        "type": "User",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock"
      }
    },
    "repository": {
      "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/{archive_format}{/ref}",
      "archived": false,
      "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/assignees{/user}",
      "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/git/blobs{/sha}",
      "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/branches{/branch}",
      "clone_url": "https://github.com/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions.git",
      "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/collaborators{/collaborator}",
      "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/comments{/number}",
      "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/commits{/sha}",
      "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/compare/{base}...{head}",
      "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/contents/{+path}",
      "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/contributors",
      "created_at": "2020-05-30 T04:08:32 Z",
      "default_branch": "master",
      "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/deployments",
      "description": null,
      "disabled": false,
      "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/downloads",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/events",
      "fork": false,
      "forks": 0,
      "forks_count": 0,
      "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/forks",
      "full_name": "colbyfayock/demo-github-actions",
      "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/git/commits{/sha}",
      "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/git/refs{/sha}",
      "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/git/tags{/sha}",
      "git_url": "git://github.com/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions.git",
      "has_downloads": true,
      "has_issues": true,
      "has_pages": false,
      "has_projects": true,
      "has_wiki": true,
      "homepage": null,
      "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/hooks",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions",
      "id": 268006728,
      "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/issues/comments{/number}",
      "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/issues/events{/number}",
      "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/issues{/number}",
      "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/keys{/key_id}",
      "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/labels{/name}",
      "language": "JavaScript",
      "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/languages",
      "license": {
        "key": "mit",
        "name": "MIT License",
        "node_id": "[node ID]",
        "spdx_id": "MIT",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/mit"
      },
      "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/merges",
      "11": 18,
      "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/milestones{/number}",
      "mirror_url": null,
      "name": "demo-github-actions",
      "node_id": "[node id]",
      "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
      "open_issues": 2,
      "open_issues_count": 2,
      "owner": {
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1045274?v=4",
        "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/events{/privacy}",
        "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/followers",
        "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/following{/other_user}",
        "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/gists{/gist_id}",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/colbyfayock",
        "id": 1045274,
        "login": "colbyfayock",
        "node_id": "[node id]",
        "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/orgs",
        "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/received_events",
        "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/repos",
        "site_admin": false,
        "starred_url": "...",
        "subscriptions_url": "...",
        "type": "User",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock"
      },
      "private": false,
      "pulls_url": "...",
      "pushed_at": "2020-05-31 T15:18:27 Z",
      "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/releases{/id}",
      "size": 52,
      "ssh_url": "git@github.com:colbyfayock/demo-github-actions.git",
      "stargazers_count": 0,
      "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/stargazers",
      "statuses_url": "...",
      "subscribers_url": "...",
      "subscription_url": "...",
      "svn_url": "https://github.com/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions",
      "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/tags",
      "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/teams",
      "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions/git/trees{/sha}",
      "updated_at": "2020-05-31 T15:18:10 Z",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/colbyfayock/demo-github-actions",
      "watchers": 0,
      "watchers_count": 0
    },
    "sender": {
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1045274?v=4",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/events{/privacy}",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/gists{/gist_id}",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/colbyfayock",
      "id": 1045274,
      "login": "colbyfayock",
      "node_id": "[node id]",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/orgs",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock/received_events",
      "repos_url": "...",
      "site_admin": false,
      "starred_url": "...",
      "subscriptions_url": "...",
      "type": "User",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/colbyfayock"
    }
  },
  "server_url": "https://github.com",
  "api_url": "https://api.github.com",
  "graphql_url": "https://api.github.com/graphql",
  "workspace": "/home/runner/work/demo-github-actions/demo-github-actions",
  "action": "abinodaslack-action",
  "event_path": "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow/event.json"
}
```