# How to release Python package only if tag is from master branch

Tags: github-actions, git-tag

I need to release package only if pushed tag is on master branch.

For now I tried something like that:

```yaml
  verification:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    container:
      image: docker_server.com/python:3.10  # fake path to docker image
      credentials:
        username: user_name
        password: user_pass
    steps:
      - name: clone repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Fetch all tags and branches
        run: |
          git tag -l | xargs git tag -d
          git fetch --all
          git fetch --tags

      - name: Check if tag is on master
        run: |
          git_tag_name="$(echo ${{ github.ref }} | cut -d'/' -f3)"
          hash_tag=$(git rev-list -n 1 $git_tag_name)
          if git branch --contains $hash_tag | sed -e 's/* //g' -e 's/ //g' | grep -w 'master'; then
              echo "Commit on master"
          else
              echo "Commit not on branch"
              exit 1
          fi
```

Those commands work on my local repository but in GitHub this job is failing with message that my tag commit is not on master.

I set fetching level to 0 but it still the same.

Comment: I suggest you print the GITHUB_CONTEXT (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70104600/complete-list-of-github-actions-contexts)) in this workflow, to see what are the field composing the github event for this pushed tag (you can also check [here for a list of documented events](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/using-the-rest-api/github-event-types?apiVersion=2022-11-28#pushevent)), and update your workflow configurations accordingly.