# git cherry-pick but is a merge

Tags: git, github, git-cherry-pick

At some point I decide to remove some files/folders from master because it was a unecesary development (at that point), but now I need those files/folders.

So, what I tried was to create a `newMaster` branch (from `master`) and to cherry-pick the commit where those files/folders were created and added to the project.

That commit was the "XYZ"

So I tried to do:

```
user@local ±|newMaster|→ git cherry-pick XYZ
error: commit XYZ is a merge but no -m option was given.
```

These are the commits that surround the one that have the files that I need:

[image]

If I look into the files of the commit `433801b` the files that I need are not there, they are added in the XYZ but is a Merge.

How can I pick those files of that commit to my newMaster?

Comment: When you cherry-pick (or e.g. revert) a merge (or other multi-parent) commit, you have to specify *with respect to which parent*.

Comment: How can I see the parents? I put `git show` on the commit that I want to pick the files but it shows me just 1 commit.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/9059335/3001761