# a strange merge happened with my project when using git

Tags: git

Today I found some of my project file conflict, but I did not merge any branch. I using the Intellij Idea show history, it looks like this:

[image]

what does this mean? it seems not merge forward but backward. why did this happen? what should I do to avoid this problem? from the `git log` command I did not found any merge operate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the commits are presented from most recent to oldest, the 2021/3/26, 10:44 commit is not a merge backward, but the point from which origin (violet) and develop (green) have diverged.

The commit from 24 minutes ago is where the two branches rejoined.
[Display the parent commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9059633/6309) of that "24 minutes" commit: you should see two parents.

It could be a `merge --ours`, where the content of your branch is preserved.